# How to load test MPEG Dash

Tags: load-testing, mpeg-dash

I have to perform load tests on a video streaming server does anybody know a good tool that can help me? if it were free or open source, it would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is nothing special in testing MPEG Dash as it is a subset of [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) so [**any** load testing tool](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) which supports [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) protocol will fit.

If you're looking for a specific recommendation check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it is free, open source, has relatively large community and you don't have to know any programming language as JMeter tests can be created using GUI approach.

Check out [Load Testing Video Streaming with JMeter: Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-video-streaming-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for detailed instructions with regards to the most popular video streaming protocols load testing using JMeter

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [commercial plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-mpeg-dash-jmeter-ubik-videostreaming-plugin/) for [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org).

It is available through jmeter-plugins manager and allows you to reastically test all flavors of MPEG-DASH.
It simulates how players download manifests, chunks, init segments and provides video related metrics.

Disclaimer: I am member of the team that delivers it